# @mention to outgoing webhook is not showing up on microsoft teams application

Tags: microsoft-teams, webhooks

@mention to outgoing webhook is not showing up on microsoft teams application. It used to show up when we provide @mention but recent updates on teams its not working.

Comment: We tried this by setting up https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/main/samples/outgoing-webhook/nodejs, and we were able to @mention the webhook and it get response - https://i.stack.imgur.com/cr84B.png. Could you please let us know if you are checking this differently?